# Oracle APEX - passing IG column value to javascript

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have an IG with a link column where the target is set to URL and I use it to call javascript.

What I want to accomplish is whenever a link column is clicked, grab a value of another - hidden column and set a page item to that value:

```
javascript:$s('P1_ITEM',#COLUMN2#);alert($v('P1_ITEM'));
```

but what happens, if I reference COLUMN2 value using just `#COLUMN#`, I get a javascript error and if I wrap it in single quotes, the value of P1_ITEM literally gets set to `#COLUMN2#`.

Comment: I would try modifying the query so that `#COLUMN2#` includes the embedded quotes.

Comment: you mean as a part of the field? like 'column2'?

Comment: As part of the data.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would recommend is that you move to a Dynamic Action rather than trying to put all the code in the link. Also, I think buttons are a better than links (and they can be styled to look like links).

Start by going to https://apex.oracle.com/ut. Navigate to Reference > Button Builder and build the button you want. Then copy the value from the **Entire Markup** field.

Change the **Type** of the Link column to **HTML Expression** and paste the HTML from the Button Builder in the **HTML Expression** field. I styled my button to look like a link (as you had it), added a custom class to the class property named **my-button**, and added a data-attribute for the primary key value (my table was EMP, so the PK was EMPNO). It looked like this in the end:

```
<button type="button" class="t-Button t-Button--link my-custom-button" data-id="&EMPNO.">Click me!</button>
```

Give the Interactive Grid a **Static ID** value of **my-ig**.

With that done, create a new Dynamic Action. Set **Name** to **.my-button clicked**, **Event** to **Click**, Selection **Type** to **jQuery Selector**, and **jQuery Selector** to **.my-button**. Finally, set **Event Scope** to **Dynamic**, which will use event delegation to keep the event binding working if the report refreshes (see [this for details](http://%20https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uK7vCqfXxNs&list=PLUo-NIMouZ_sgdQpMbXXwhHKpwRggCY34&index=5&t=22m42s)).

In the action, set **Action** to **Execute JavaScript Code**. Enter the following code in the **Code** field:

```
var id = $(this.triggeringElement).data('id');
var model = apex.region('my-ig').call('getViews').grid.model;
var record = model.getRecord(id);
var job = model.getValue(record, 'JOB');

$s('P1_ITEM', job);

alert($v('P1_ITEM'));
```

This code starts by obtaining the value of the primary key from the data- attribute on the button using jQuery's `data` method. Next, a reference to the model that is used by the IG is obtained. Then the model's `getRecord` method is invoked and the primary key value is passed in. Finally, the model's `getValue` method is used to get the 'JOB' value from the record. I went after the JOB column since I was using the EMP table, but you would go after whatever column you need.

You can learn more about the model methods here:
https://apex.oracle.com/js > Interfaces > Model.

Comment: I really need to figure out how to just set the page item value based on a column value and I really need to do this in the link. Can you help?

Comment: You said two things 1) I really need to figure out how to just set the page item value based on a column value and 2) I really need to do this in the link. Regarding 1, didn't I show you how to do that? Regarding 2, can you please explain why? I'm just curious.

Comment: Does this: var id = $(this.triggeringElement).data('id'); still work in APEX 20.2? For me this code returns "undefined". I have 2 columns (in a IG) with radio groups that I need to check their values and based on the results run some javascript but I can't seem to find a way to do this that works

Comment: Note that `var id = $(this.triggeringElement).data('id');`, so that should work unless jQuery was updated and they changed that method. However, the fact that you're getting `undefined` indicates the method is still there. Look at the button HTML and you'll see this: `data-id="&EMPNO."`. I'm using that to map the EMPNO value to the HTML element as a "data" attribute. jQuery's data method allows me to get that value. Make sure you have something like that too.

Comment: Thanks for the input... I tried adding data-id="&ID." to the advanced -> custom attributes of the column but it is not picking up the ID. When I inspect the grid I just see "data-id" . I have tried other methods of picking up the id : var id = $(this.triggeringElement).closest('tr').data('id') but this returns undefined as well.

Comment: Just to be sure, "ID" is the primary key column name/alias and it is in the query for the region?

Comment: Yes....the result is the same be it the column is hidden...not hidden...

Comment: I ended up going another route:

var grid = apex.region('ig_region_id').widget().interactiveGrid('getViews','grid');
var model = grid.model;
var selectedRow = grid.view$.grid('getSelection');
var id = $(selectedRow[0][0]).data('id');
var record = model.getRecord(id);