# How to access an entered Interactive Grid column value in a Javascript dynamic action on the Change event in order to ensure uniqueness

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-20.2

I am trying to prevent duplicate items from being entered in an Interactive Grid in Oracle Apex 20.2. I do get a unique constraint error when this happens, but this is for a barcode scanning stock control app and the unique constraint error only happens when saving after scanning a room with lots of objects. It is then very difficult to find the duplicate field. You also cannot use sort, since that wants to refresh the page and looses all your scanned items. I cannot presort because I want the last scanned item on top.

I was able to add Javascript on page load that creates an array with all the barcodes. I then check this array when scanning and do not add new Interactive Grid rows when a duplicate barcode is going to be added to the array.

In addition to this I need to add the same for when an Interactive Grid row is manually entered. For this I wanted to add a Javascript dynamic action on the barcode column in the Interactive Grid, in order to once again check the global array for uniqueness. However I have several issues: I cannot figure out how the get the entered barcode value in the change dynamic action Javascript, sometimes it shows the previous changed value (might be [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62203299/interactive-grid-javascript-getvalue) although I am in 20.2) and the Change event also seems to fire twice when hitting enter after entering a value (once for the new row (this time my code works unlike when hitting Tab) and once for the next row below). The last one seems bad, since then it will try to check existing values (the next row) and give errors that should not happen; however I do not see a more appropriate event like On Row Submit. Not sure if there is a way to check whether the value changed on the Change event.

The code I currently have I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60756787/oracle-apex-passing-ig-column-value-to-javascript). I am assuming this means Oracle Apex does not have a standard way of getting an Interactive Grid column value in a Javascript dynamic action. Not sure if this has changed in 20.2 or 21. The code I have is:

```
console.log($(this.triggeringElement));
var grid = apex.region('LINES').widget().interactiveGrid('getViews', 'grid'); 
var model = grid.model; 
var selectedRow = grid.view$.grid('getSelection'); 
var id = $(selectedRow[0][0]).data('id'); 
var record = model.getRecord(id);
let bcode = model.getValue(record, 'BARCODE');
console.log(id);
console.log(record);
console.log($(selectedRow[0][0]));
console.log(bcode);

if(barcodes.includes(bcode)) {
    apex.message.showErrors([{
        type: "error",
        location: "page",
        message: "The entered barcode is already in the list.",
        unsafe: false
    }]);
}
```

When I `console.log(record)` I can see values that I enter into the barcode column, but I do not know how to walk the object tree in order to retrieve the value out of the `record`. I do not understand the object it shows me in the console log. It does not seem to correlate with the dot access traversals that others are doing in the above code. I can see the `record` array at the top, but for that the barcode column shows the previous value; below that it does however show the newly entered value as the third (2) index, but I do not know how to write Javascript to access that.

If I can access the previous and new value from the `record` object I could check for changes and also compare the new value against the global array. How do I access these values in the `record` object or is there a better way of achieving my goal? `bcode` prints the previous value, so I guess I already have that if that is not a bug.

[image: Console output]

Comment: Also not sure whether the selected row part of the code is the best, since multiple rows could be selected I guess.

Comment: Your post is really broad and I am missing specific questions. Do you need code to compare the value a user has just entered to the other values in the same column?

Comment: @ThomasTschernich Yes. I am trying to use Javascript to prevent duplicate values from being entered.